# Wordpress form redirect on submit from select dropdown of pages

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, redirect

In wordpress I've got a dropdown of posts as select options, after they've selected a post and hit submit, how would you go about sending them to that page itself?

Comment: Please post more information, including sample code or solutions you've currently tried. This could be handled with a PHP handler on the form action or by listening to the `change` event on the select field with jQuery.

Comment: Tried adding existing code for you, for some reason stacks skitzing out and won't actually display the code. I've already tried solutions which is why I've come here, appreciate the notes in the right direction though.